# Azure Site Recovery - CentOS 8.3 unsupported kernel

Tags: azure, centos, disaster-recovery

I'm trying to protect a vmware vm centos 8.3, but I'm getting unsupported kernel error.

> - The current kernel is 4.18.0-240 and I didn't find anywhere centos compatible kernel versions.
> - Mobility service is being installed in auto mode.
> - Configuration Server version: 9.42.1.0
> - Agent version: 5.1.6784.0

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some kernel versions may have LIS components missing. You can try installing [LIS components](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=55106) again and then try to enable the replication.

**Reference**:

[Support matrix for vmware to azure](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/site-recovery/vmware-physical-azure-support-matrix#for-linux)

[ASR CENTOS 8.3](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/topic/update-rollup-52-for-azure-site-recovery-c98af2b9-74af-8796-3184-d1d292bf3344)

Comment: Found the problem. The secure boot option on vm options at vcenter, must be disabled.
Thanks for your help

Comment: Glad to hear that it helped!